# Injecting additional text in a string

Tags: python, regex

Bascially I have two strings, one biography and the other is year_of_birth.

biography content is:

> abc abc abc abc.
>
> Born in England. abc abc abc.
>
> abc abc abc abc.

year_of_birth is a number. Say 1920.

My disired output is:

> abc abc abc abc.
>
> Born in England **in 1920**. abc abc abc.
>
> abc abc abc abc.

So I simply want to inject ***in 1920*** IF born keyword is found and after any A-Z chars but before any punctuation.

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you get the **in 1920**?

Comment: Use string formating:  `'Born in England in %s. abc abc' % 1920` if you can change the input

Comment: @JBernardo: Don't you mean `%d`?

Comment: @JBernardo The text is coming from the database and may not contains Born...

Comment: You should provide a sample of all the ``Born..`` lines as there may be 'places' which break the regexp. To exaggerate "Born in U.S.A" (Bruce?) would make it fail. Granted you know your data so you might have it covered in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> year_of_birth = 1920
>>> re.sub('(?m)[bB]orn[^,.?!:;]+', '\g<0> in %d' % year_of_birth, content)
'abc abc abc abc.\n\nBorn in England in 1920. abc abc abc.\n\nabc abc abc abc.'
```

Here `[^,.?!:;]+` is matching anything that's not a punctuation.
Also, `(?m)` indicates multiline, in case the punctuation is on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.sub(r'(Born.*?)\.', r'\1 in 1920.', bio)
```